# How to shift/offset a AC signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, level-shifting

I have made the following circuit, that amplifies a 50mV RMS signal to 0 to 5V.

The circuit has 2 2nd order LPF at unity gain and a 30dB (30 V/V) gain amplifier. Below is a circuit diagram:

[image]

Input signal:

[image]

Output signal (Vout):

[image]

AC analysis:

[image]

Output noise:

[image]

My question:

I want to now shift the Vout signal by 2.5V, can someone advise what circuit I use to achieve this?

Comment: The answer to your question is to look up the usual "summing" or "adder' op amp circuit, and set up a resistor divider to give you the voltage that is added.

Comment: By the way - nice schematic.  Good spacing, very readable.  Only thing - the GND symbol above R12.  Grounds ***always*** point down.  Unlike most schematic symbols, the direction of the GND symbol is part of its definition.  No rotation allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit has some serious issues, and will not work with real world components.

Most of the resistors are way too small.  For example, the output stage has a corner frequency of over 3.5 MHz, and expects the chip to drive a 300 ohm load.

What is the purpose of R3 and R8?

What is the bandwidth of the signal you are working with?  Is there a reason you are using a 100 kHz circuit for a 50 Hz signal?

UPDATE:

In the output stage, R17 and C15 form a lowpass filter with a corner frequency of over 3.5 MHz.  This seems very high for an input signal of 50 Hz.  Also, to deliver flat frequency response out to 3.5 MHz with a gain of thirty, that is a GBW of over 105 million.  This is say more that the chip can deliver.

This chip's GBW is stated as 10 million, so the max signal frequency for a gain of 30 is around 330 kHz.  This means that the chip is acting as a 330 kHz lowpass filter despite the circuit requirement indicated by your component values.  And even at that frequency, there is almost zero negative feedback to stabilize the operating point, drive up the input impedance, drive down the output impedance, etc.

A good rule of thumb is that the chip's open loop gain at the highest frequency of interest should be at least 20 dB greater than the required gain.  That is, if you want 30 dB of gain at 100 kHz, the chip should be able to deliver 50 dB or more.  Per fig. 12 on the datasheet, the chip can deliver 40 dB.  That is enough to close the loop, but barely.

One way around this is to change the filter stages so they contribute signal gain.  If each filter stage had a gain of 2, then the output stage would need a gain of less than 8.

All of the current in R17 comes from the opamp output stage.  The chip is rated for a max output current of 35 mA.  The chip can handle the 25 mA peak output current needed for your required output voltage, but that is placing an unnecessary stress on the output stage.  If you do not have a specific reason for the low value resistors, I recommend increasing them by at least 10x (and scaling the capacitor values accordingly).

One way to inject a DC offset into the output is to replace R12 with a 2-resistor divider, between one of the voltage rails and GND, that has the same Thevenin equivalent resistance.  Again, a larger resistor value here would be advantageous, as it would give you a much larger range of standard resistor values to work with.

Comment: R3 is a shunt resistor R8 is the load. How do you get the corner freq to be over 3.5MHz? Why would small resistor values not work in real-world (they do exist, so what is the reason)?

Comment: The bandwidth, for now, is 100kHz

Answer (score 0):

To level shift it you can simply replace R12 with two resistors connected from a negative reference voltage to ground. The gain from the inverting input is -30 (+31 from the non-inverting input). If your reference is say -2.5V (perhaps from a shunt reference chip) one resistor would be equal to R17 and the other would be 1/Rg = 1/R12-1/17.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFdNVt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But pay attention to what @analogkid said about bandwidth and too-low resistor values.

Also if you should ever think about substituting a lower performance op-amp, this entire circuit is DC-coupled so the offset voltages will be added and then multiplied by the gain of 31. That's less than 8mV with the AD8675 so not too distressing.

And, if you're planning on going from the op-amp output into an ADC with 5V supply rails you'll likely have to worry about clamping the op-amp output so as not to damage the ADC input.

Comment: Why is it wrong to use small resistor values?

Comment: The equation in your answer seems confusing, there is no R12 in your schematic

Comment: R12 is the *value* of the one in your schematic.  It's just the Thevenin equivalent (the two resistors I mention, in parallel, are equal that value).

Comment: Small resistor values mean too much current from the op-amp, excessive bandwidth (if it is for your application) can cause other issues.

Comment: Is R12 from my schematic equal to Rg in your schematic?

Comment: No, Rg is a smidge higher, as the equation reflects.

Comment: Your equation 1/Rg = 1/R12-1/R17 makes reference to your schematic and my schematic, hence the confusion. Where would R12 in my schematic fit in your schematic?

Comment: If you use 3K and 100 ohms in your schematic, 1/Rg = 1/100 - 1/3k

Comment: I am only measuring a 50Hz sine wave. Should I rather just use maybe a 100Hz bandwidth instead? I am not sure of how to choose the bandwidth if I only require the 50Hz sine wave.

Answer (score 0):

> I am only measuring a 50Hz sine wave. Should I rather just use maybe a 100Hz bandwidth instead? I am not sure of how to choose the bandwidth if I only require the 50Hz sine wave.

That was one of my questions.  What are you trying to measure?

1. What are the corner frequencies of your two lowpass filter stages?  And, why?
2. What aspects of the input signal are you trying to pass, and what aspects are you trying to filter out?  A specific noise frequency?  Ambient radiated noise from misc sources?  Harmonic distortion products?
3. If the signal is being measured by an A/D converter, what is the resolution in bits ans what is the sampling rate in hertz?  These values can be used to optimize the filter design.
4. Even a perfect lowpass filter's performance is not a perfectly flat response up to the corner frequency.  For example, a 100 Hz single-pole lowpass filter's response is down 3dB at 100 Hz (a 30% decrease), and 1 dB at 50 Hz.  To this you have to add in the effects of non-perfect components, especially resistor and capacitor value tolerances.  These have the effect of making the frequency corner much less sharp, increasing amplitude response errors at lower frequencies and reducing the actual attenuation at higher frequencies.

But wait - there's more.  Two two-pole filters in series and a true four-pole filter are not the same thing.  The two-filter circuit will have a much "rounder" (less flat) frequency response curve, and four-pole circuit will require strange resistor and capacitor values.  Really good filters are tough.  Start with the frequencies you are concerned with, and the amount of attenuation you think you need, and grow the filter spcc around those parameters.

If you want zero attenuation at 50 Hz, the filter corner frequency should be at least 200 Hz.  Unless I knew of a specific noise component I wanted to eliminate, I would start with 1 kHz.